# SonarQube is creating two java processes

Tags: sonarqube

i just noticed that sonarqube is creating two java.exe processes. 
what is the reason behind this?
Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube is actually creating 3 processes since SonarQube 5.5. Everything is clearly explained in the ["Architecture and Integration" page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+and+Integration) of the documentation:

> One SonarQube Server starting 3 main processes:
>
> - a Web Server for developers, managers to browse quality snapshots and configure the SonarQube instance
> - a Search Server based on Elasticsearch to back searches from the UI
> - a Compute Engine Server in charge of processing code analysis reports and saving them in the SonarQube Database

Comment: Thanks much for the response. Appreciated